# Google Apps Script - login button not functioning properly - how to retrieve name from Google Sheet

Tags: php, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a form for an NGO to share reports to their members (more than 100).
In the form, the member would need to insert their ID (nric) and their email and it will validate it with the list of existing members. Upon successful validation, a second page will be shown where the link to download the report will be made available.

I followed a guide on youtube to create a simple 2 page Google Sheet app and Apps Script.
The original guide is intended for user to login with username and password. I made some changes for the members to login with ID and Email instead. Upon testing with the right ID and emails, I am able to login.

Below are my enquiries:

1. Currently the form has an issue. If I leave the login form totally empty (empty email and ID) and when I click on the login button, it will login successfully. If I insert either ID or email wrongly, it successfully display the error message. What did I miss?
2. Someone in the youtube comment pointed out that the
   "touppercase from the checkLogin function, that don't work anymore in app script"
   Can anyone confirm?
3. Once the member login, I want to display that person name. In the original code, it display the username if only the user insert the username, while I want to retrieve it from the Google Sheet column 1.

Original code to retrieve username

```
document.getElementById("displayusername").innerHTML = username;
```

How do I retrieve the member name from column 1 of that member that login from the Google Sheet that link to the Apps Script?

Thank you very much

I have 2 files, "Code.gs" and "index.html"

**Code.gs**

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var x = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  var y = x.evaluate();
  var z = y.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return z;
}

function checkLogin(nric,email) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dKcn__IcRnDoXf72HnsVN7L2POSNu8KzKJKpS4jmNrk/edit#gid=0';
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
  var found_record = '';
  for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
   if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue().toUpperCase() == nric.toUpperCase() && 
 webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue().toUpperCase() == email.toUpperCase())
   {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
   }    
  }
  if(found_record == '')
  {
    found_record = 'FALSE'; 
  }
  
  return found_record;
  
}

function AddRecord(usernamee, nricc, emaill, phone) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dKcn__IcRnDoXf72HnsVN7L2POSNu8KzKJKpS4jmNrk/edit#gid=0';
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  webAppSheet.appendRow([usernamee,nricc,emaill,phone]);
  
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function AddRow()
    {
      var usernamee = document.getElementById("usernamee").value;
      var nricc = document.getElementById("nricc").value;
      var emaill = document.getElementById("emaill").value;
      var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
      if (usernamee==""|| nricc==""|| emaill==""|| phone=="") {
        return false;
      }
      else {
      google.script.run.AddRecord(usernamee,nricc,emaill,phone);
      document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1-off";
      document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1";
     }
    }

     function LoginUser()
    {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var nric = document.getElementById("nric").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
    {
      if(output == 'TRUE')
      {
         document.getElementById("displayusername").innerHTML = username;
         document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_class1-off";
         document.getElementById("page4_id1").className = "page4_id1";    
      }
      else if(output == 'FALSE')
      {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please login with your email and your NRIC(with dashes). If you are unable to login, please contact ERA at era@era.org.my to update your information.";     
      }    
    }).checkLogin(nric,email);
    }
    
function function1(){
    document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_class1-off";
    document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1";
}
 
function function3(){ 
  document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1-off";
  document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_id1"; 
}

  </script>
  <style>
/*button*/
.reportbutton {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.buttongreen {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */

/*page1*/
.page1_class1-off{
    display: none;
  }


/*page2*/
.page2_class1{
    display: none;
  }

.page2_id1-off{
    display:none;
}

/*page3*/
.page3_class1{
    display:none;

}
.page3_id1-off{
    display:none;
}

/*page4*/
.page4_class1{
    display:none;

}
.page4_id1-off{
    display:none;
}

input[type=text]:hover{
        border-bottom:2px solid black;
      }
input[type=number]:hover{
        border-bottom:2px solid black;
      }
input[type=password]:hover{
        border-bottom:2px solid black;
      }

.user{
display: inline-block;
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
border: 8px solid black;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*the head/*/
.user::before{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: black;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 11px);
top: 10px;
}

/*the body*/
.user::after{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width:50px;
height:40px;
background: black;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 24px);
top: 39px;
}

</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br>
<!--page1-->
<center>
 <div class="page1_class1" id="page1_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;"> 
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Full Name" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="nric" placeholder="NRIC (eg : 999999-10-9999)" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
    <br><span id="errorMessage" style="color: red" ></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"  style="float: right;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 1px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight:bold;" /><br>
    <br>
    
 </div>
<!--page3-->
 <div class="page3_class1" id="page3_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;"><center>
    <h2> Your account has been successfully created. Login to your account</h2>
    <input type="submit"  onClick="function3()" value="Login" style="font-weight:bold;"><br>
 </div> 

<!--page4-->
<div class="page4_class1" id="page4_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;" ><center>
    <br>
    <h2>Hi <b id="displayusername" style="color:red;"></b>!</h2>
    <div class="user"></div>
    <h2> You have successfully logged in.</h2>
    <h2> Download the report below.</h2>
    <a class="reportbutton buttongreen" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Report 1</a>
    <a class="reportbutton buttongreen" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Report 2</a>
    <a class="reportbutton buttongreen" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Report 3</a>
    <h2>**************</h2>
    <br>
  </div>
</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_If I leave the login form totally empty (empty email and ID) and when I click on the login button, it will login successfully_". That's really a problem and not the least. Why don't you check if nric and email are not empty...? In the "LoginUser" function for example...?

Comment: You are right, there is one row where both are empty. That one issue solved. Thank you.
Any idea for the other 2 questions?